# Problems injecting kinvey into angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kinvey

I am having some trouble injecting kinvey into my angular application. I have been getting the following error with the code below: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]`

```
var app = angular.module('FantasySeasons', ['snap', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngTouch',
 'angular-carousel', 'FSControllers', 'FSPartials', 'kinvey']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
            controller : 'HomeCtrl'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/'
        });
    }]);


    app.run(function($kinvey){
        var promise = $kinvey.init({
            appKey: 'your app key',
            appSecret: 'your app secret'
        });
    });
```

Comment: Show your `script=src`

Answer (score 1):

As the creator of the Kinvey Angular library, I don’t see anything wrong with declaring the Kinvey dependency.

Since the error message is not specific to any module, I can only guess at this point. One thing to note is the `ngRoute` module is no longer part of the AngularJS core (since 1.2.0). To use it, you need to include it separately, see [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute). Make sure this is the case. Otherwise, you run into that error.